# Node types from @types/node not applying as expected

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm starting to re-tool for TypeScript, and I'm loving it so far.  However, I still run across mysterious behavior that makes me think I'm missing something.  For example, I ran into an "implicit 'any'" type error (I have `strict: true`, and want that) that, as best I can tell, should be covered by `@types/node`.  I am able to fix it, of course, by explicitly typing it, but I want to know why the typing from `@types/node` is not being recognized.

1. Create `package.json`: `npm init -y` (not strictly necessary, but helpful)
2. Install TypeScript, Node 12 tsconfig defaults, and Node types: `npm i -D typescript @tsconfig/node12 @types/node`
3. Create `tsconfig.json` (see below)
4. Create `src/demo.ts` (see below)
5. Run `tsc`: `./node_modules/.bin/tsc`

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node12/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src"
  }
}
```

`src/demo.ts`:

```js
const http = require('http')

http.get('http://google.com', res => console.log(res))
```

Following these steps yields the following type error:

```
src/demo.ts:3:31 - error TS7006: Parameter 'res' implicitly has an 'any' type.

3 http.get('http://google.com', res => console.log(res))
```

Unless I'm missing something, the typing in `@types/node` should be able to infer that `res` is of type `IncomingMessage`.  From [line 403 of `http.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/fcb257683af38b3e64981393946a35f2cc1b15fa/types/node/http.d.ts#L403) (formatted for SO):

```js
function get(
  options: RequestOptions | string | URL,
  callback?: (res: IncomingMessage) => void
): ClientRequest;
```

I looked into `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.json`, and the TS documentation states that that's not necessary (the types should be found automatically in `node_modules`).  I also tried `/// <reference types="node" />` to no avail.

I would love to understand why `ref` isn't being recognized as type `IncomingMessage`.

Package versions:

- `@tsconfig/node12: ^1.0.7`
- `@types/node: ^14.11.10`
- `@types/typescript: ^4.0.3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Types for imported modules don't come into effect unless you use an ES import. Change the wrong code to the correct code as shown below:

## Wrong

```
const http = require('http')

http.get('http://google.com', res => console.log(res))
```

## Correct

```
import * as http from 'http'

http.get('http://google.com', res => console.log(res))
```

Comment: Ah, that explains that...that's really good to know, thank you!

Comment: Kind of makes me wish TypeScript would warn me about CJS imports!